# Как сделать плавный переход при исчезновении объекта?

Tags: css, css3

У меня есть карта, а над ней расположен текст, они занимают всю страницу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На карте есть кнопка для увеличения карты на весь экран.

при нажатии на нее я просто меняю стили у текста

```
.main__text{
padding: 50px 10%;
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
}
.main__text.visible{
    position: inherit;
    visibility: inherit;
}
```

Все отлично работает, карта увеличивается, текст исчезает. Но карта очень резко увеличивается, и происходит "дерганье". Как сделать так чтобы карта расширялась плавно(у нее стили стоят width:100% и height: 100%)

Comment: через transition: all 0.3s ease 0s; пробовали?

Comment: Как вставлена карта? Если через `iframe` ("виджет" карты), то никак, если в документации нет об этом информации.

Comment: через transition пробовала, карта создана с помощью Leaflet.

Comment: думаю, тебе поможет только документация Leaflet. Средствами css это может и не сработать.